# Pandas count values greater than current row in the last n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to get count of values greater than current row in the last n rows?

Imagine we have a dataframe as following:

```
    col_a
0    8.4
1   11.3
2    7.2
3    6.5
4    4.5
5    8.9
```

I am trying to get a table such as following where n=3.

```
    col_a   col_b
0     8.4       0
1    11.3       0
2     7.2       2
3     6.5       3
4     4.5       3
5     8.9       0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In pandas is best dont loop because slow, here is better use [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with custom function:

```
n = 3
df['new'] = (df['col_a'].rolling(n+1, min_periods=1)
                        .apply(lambda x: (x[-1] < x[:-1]).sum())
                        .astype(int))
print (df)
   col_a  new
0    8.4    0
1   11.3    0
2    7.2    2
3    6.5    3
4    4.5    3
5    8.9    0
```

If performance is important, use [strides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48884154/2901002):

```
n = 3
x = np.concatenate([[np.nan] * (n), df['col_a'].values])

def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
arr = rolling_window(x, n + 1)

df['new'] = (arr[:, :-1] > arr[:, [-1]]).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   col_a  new
0    8.4    0
1   11.3    0
2    7.2    2
3    6.5    3
4    4.5    3
5    8.9    0
```

**Performance**: Here is used [`perfplot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) in small window `n = 3`:

[image: g1]

```
np.random.seed(1256)
n = 3

def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def roll(df):
    df['new'] = (df['col_a'].rolling(n+1, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: (x[-1] < x[:-1]).sum(), raw=True).astype(int))
    return df

def list_comp(df):
    df['count'] = [(j < df['col_a'].iloc[max(0, i-3):i]).sum() for i, j in df['col_a'].items()]
    return df

def strides(df):
    x = np.concatenate([[np.nan] * (n), df['col_a'].values])
    arr = rolling_window(x, n + 1)
    df['new1'] = (arr[:, :-1] > arr[:, [-1]]).sum(axis=1)
    return df


def make_df(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=n), columns=['col_a'])
    return df

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[list_comp, roll, strides],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 15)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

Also I was curious about performance in large window, `n = 100`:

[image: g2]

Comment: I can confirm this outperforms other answers by far. I am new to pandas, I just couldn't figure out how to filter out rolling series.

Comment: @koray1396 - Question was really interesting and answers a bit slow, so try added better one. So recommended use this - `rolling` is simplier, `strides` complicated, but faster.

Comment: @koray1396 - In pandas is simplier rule, avoid `loops` like list comprehensions if exist better faster vectorized solutions.

Comment: Just to be clear the `roll` method is faster but it's still not vectorised because of the `apply` + `lambda`. The `strides` method is indeed vectorised and an excellent solution if you can understand the logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 3
df['col_b'] = df.apply(lambda row: sum(row.col_a <= df.col_a.loc[row.name - n: row.name-1]), axis=1)

Out[]: 
   col_a  col_b
0    8.4      0
1   11.3      0
2    7.2      2
3    6.5      3
4    4.5      3
5    8.9      0
```

Comment: Unfortnately your code give wrong output, so cannot add to timings. sorry.

Comment: @jezrael What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension with `pd.Series.items`:

```
n = 3
df['count'] = [(j < df['col_a'].iloc[max(0, i-3):i]).sum() \
               for i, j in df['col_a'].items()]
```

Equivalently, using `enumerate`:

```
n = 3
df['count'] = [(j < df['col_a'].iloc[max(0, i-n):i]).sum() \
               for i, j in enumerate(df['col_a'])]
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   col_a  count
0    8.4      0
1   11.3      0
2    7.2      2
3    6.5      3
4    4.5      3
5    8.9      0
```