# Given a value or constant, I need to only output relevant rows on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is how my data looks like:

```
Day Price A Price B Price C
1     0        0      0
2     0        0      0
3     0        0      0
4     0        0      0
5   64503   43692   79982
6   86664   69990   53468
7   77924   62998   68911
8   66600   68830   94396
9   82664   89972   49614
10  59741   48904   49528
11  34030   98074   72993
12  74400   85547   37715
13  51031   50031   85345
14  74700   59932   73935
15  62290   98130   88818
```

I have a small python script that outputs a sum for each column. I need to input an n value (for number of days) and the summing will run and output the values.

However, for example, given n=5 (for days), I want to output only Price A/B/C rows starting from the next day (which is day 6). Hence, the row for Day 5 should be '0'.

How can I produce this logic on Pandas ?

The idea I have is to use the n input value to then, truncate values on the rows corresponding to that particular (n day value). But how can I do this on code ?

```
if dataframe['Day'] == n:
    dataframe['Price A'] == 0 & dataframe['Price B'] == 0 & dataframe['Price C'] == 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: vectorize local range operations (max & sum for \[i:i+2\] rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305799/pandas-vectorize-local-range-operations-max-sum-for-ii2-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter rows by condition and set all columns without first by `iloc[mask, 1:]`, for next row add [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
n = 5
df.iloc[(df['Day'].shift() <= n).values, 1:] = 0
print (df)
    Day  Price A  Price B  Price C
0     1        0        0        0
1     2        0        0        0
2     3        0        0        0
3     4        0        0        0
4     5        0        0        0
5     6        0        0        0
6     7    77924    62998    68911
7     8    66600    68830    94396
8     9    82664    89972    49614
9    10    59741    48904    49528
10   11    34030    98074    72993
11   12    74400    85547    37715
12   13    51031    50031    85345
13   14    74700    59932    73935
14   15    62290    98130    88818
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo Code

- Make sure to sort by day
- shift columns 'A', 'B' and 'C' by `n` and fill in with 0
- Sum accordingly

All of that can be done on one line as well

Answer (score 1):

It is simply

```py
dataframe.iloc[:n+1] = 0
```

This sets the values of all columns for the first `n` days to 0

```py
# Sample output

dataframe
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
3  4  2
4  5  3

n = 1
dataframe.iloc[:n+1] = 0

dataframe
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  0
2  3  4
3  4  2
4  5  3
```

This truncates all for all the previous days. If you want to truncate only for the `nth` day.

```py
dataframe.iloc[n] = 0
```