# Create new column based on values in other column

Tags: python, pandas

This is a column from my DataFrame:

```
Index    Direction Output
10886    DOWN      None
10887      UP      None
10888      UP      None
10889      UP      None
10890      UP      None
10891      UP      STRONG_UP
10892      UP      STRONG_UP
10893      UP      STRONG_UP
10894      UP      STRONG_UP
10895      UP      STRONG_UP
10896      UP      STRONG_UP
10897      UP      STRONG_UP
10898      UP      STRONG_UP
10899      UP      STRONG_UP
10900    DOWN      None 
10901    DOWN      None
10902      UP      None
10903      UP      None
10904    DOWN      None
10905    DOWN      None
10906    DOWN      None
```

I want to create new column.
If current Direction value and 5 previous Direction values == UP, cell becomes 'STRONG_UP'
If current Direction value and 5 previous Direction values == DOWN, cell becomes 'STRONG_DOWN'
Otherwise value is 'None'
How to do it?

Comment: can you add your expected output?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately `rolling` working only with numbers, so is used decode and encode by `map`, but is is slow if large DataFrame:

```
def f(x):
    if np.all(x == 1):
        return 2
    elif np.all(x == 0):
        return 3
    else:
        return np.nan
        

df['Output'] = df['Direction'].map({'UP':1,'DOWN':0})
                              .rolling(6)
                              .apply(f)
                              .map({2:'STRONG_UP',3:'STRONG_DOWN'})
```

---

```
print (df)
    Index Direction     Output
0   10887        UP        NaN
1   10888        UP        NaN
2   10889        UP        NaN
3   10890        UP        NaN
4   10891        UP        NaN
5   10892        UP  STRONG_UP
6   10893        UP  STRONG_UP
7   10894        UP  STRONG_UP
8   10895        UP  STRONG_UP
9   10896        UP  STRONG_UP
10  10897        UP  STRONG_UP
11  10898        UP  STRONG_UP
12  10899        UP  STRONG_UP
13  10900      DOWN        NaN
14  10901      DOWN        NaN
15  10902        UP        NaN
16  10903        UP        NaN
17  10904      DOWN        NaN
18  10905      DOWN        NaN
19  10906      DOWN        NaN
```

Another idea with [strides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883784/pandas-rolling-values/48884154#48884154) and [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) if performance is important:

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

n = 6
x = np.concatenate([[None] * (n-1), df['Direction'].to_numpy()])

a = rolling_window(x, n)
```

---

```
print (a)
[[None None None None None 'UP']
 [None None None None 'UP' 'UP']
 [None None None 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 [None None 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 [None 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'DOWN']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'DOWN' 'DOWN']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'UP' 'DOWN' 'DOWN' 'DOWN']
 ['UP' 'UP' 'DOWN' 'DOWN' 'DOWN' 'UP']
 ['UP' 'DOWN' 'DOWN' 'DOWN' 'UP' 'UP']
 ['DOWN' 'DOWN' 'DOWN' 'UP' 'UP' 'DOWN']
 ['DOWN' 'DOWN' 'UP' 'UP' 'DOWN' 'DOWN']]

m1 = np.all(a == 'UP', axis=1)
m2 = np.all(a == 'DOWN', axis=1)

df['Output'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['STRONG_UP','STRONG_DOWN'], None)
```

---

```
print (df)
    Index Direction     Output
0   10887        UP       None
1   10888        UP       None
2   10889        UP       None
3   10890        UP       None
4   10891        UP       None
5   10892        UP  STRONG_UP
6   10893        UP  STRONG_UP
7   10894        UP  STRONG_UP
8   10895        UP  STRONG_UP
9   10896        UP  STRONG_UP
10  10897        UP  STRONG_UP
11  10898        UP  STRONG_UP
12  10899        UP  STRONG_UP
13  10900      DOWN       None
14  10901      DOWN       None
15  10902      DOWN       None
16  10903        UP       None
17  10904        UP       None
18  10905      DOWN       None
19  10906      DOWN       None
```

**Performance**: Forst methof was omitted, because too slow.

```
print (pd.show_versions())


INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : f2ca0a2665b2d169c97de87b8e778dbed86aea07
python           : 3.8.5.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Windows
OS-release       : 7
Version          : 6.1.7601
machine          : AMD64
processor        : Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : en
LOCALE           : Slovak_Slovakia.1250

pandas           : 1.1.1
numpy            : 1.19.1
```

---

```
import perfplot

np.random.seed(123)


def GW(df):
    df['group'] = np.r_[True, df.Direction.values[1:] != df.Direction.values[:-1]].cumsum()
    df['count'] = df.groupby('group').cumcount()+1
    df['result'] = np.where(df['count'] >= 6, 'STRONG_'+df.Direction, np.nan) 
    df = (df[['Index','Direction','result']])
    return df

def ST(df):
    
    def rolling_window(a, window):
        shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
        strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
        return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

    n = 6
    x = np.concatenate([[None] * (n-1), df['Direction'].to_numpy()])
    a = rolling_window(x, n)
    m1 = np.all(a == 'UP', axis=1)
    m2 = np.all(a == 'DOWN', axis=1)
    df['Output2'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['STRONG_UP','STRONG_DOWN'], None)
    return df
```

---

```
def make_df(n):
    direction = np.random.choice(['UP','DOWN'], n)
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Index': np.arange(len(direction)),
        'Direction': direction
    })
    return df

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[GW, ST],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(5, 25)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

[image: g]

Comment: it is easy for me to call column cells 1 and 0 (not strings).

Comment: I like the pure pandas solution with rolling.

Comment: This is a great way to run benchmarks to compare functions. Mind if I copy your code for future benchmarks?

Comment: @mikksu - Sure, some are from me, some from pir or coldspeed, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+perfplot)

Comment: @jezrael, Woww that's great answer, thank you for sharing sir cheers.

Answer (score 1):

An Idea with numpy and no applied function

```
import numpy as np
df['group'] = np.r_[True, df.Direction.values[1:] != df.Direction.values[:-1]].cumsum()
df['count'] = df.groupby('group').cumcount()+1
df['result'] = np.where(df['count'] >= 6, 'STRONG_'+df.Direction, np.nan) 
print(df[['Index','Direction','result']])
```

Output

```
    Index Direction     result
0   10887        UP        NaN
1   10888        UP        NaN
2   10889        UP        NaN
3   10890        UP        NaN
4   10891        UP        NaN
5   10892        UP  STRONG_UP
6   10893        UP  STRONG_UP
7   10894        UP  STRONG_UP
8   10895        UP  STRONG_UP
9   10896        UP  STRONG_UP
10  10897        UP  STRONG_UP
11  10898        UP  STRONG_UP
12  10899        UP  STRONG_UP
13  10900      DOWN        NaN
14  10901      DOWN        NaN
15  10902        UP        NaN
16  10903        UP        NaN
17  10904      DOWN        NaN
18  10905      DOWN        NaN
19  10906      DOWN        NaN
```

---

### Micro-Benchmarking

Out of curiuosity I run a little benchmark on my laptop (i5-7200u, 8GB Ram, in Jupyter Notebook)

- Pandas Rolling & Apply (RA)
- Pandas GroupBy & Numpy Where (GW)
- Numpy Stride (NP)

Data was generated like

```
direction = np.random.choice(['UP','DOWN'], 100000)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Index': np.arange(len(direction)),
    'Direction': direction
})
```

Results

```
          N=1000       |      N=10000      |     N=100000
RA   32.7 ms ± 3.05 ms |  271 ms ± 22.9 ms | 2.35 s ± 60.1 ms
GW   6.33 ms ± 230 µs  | 10.2 ms ± 51.4 µs | 63.8 ms ± 1.31 ms
NP   1.33 ms ± 32.5 µs | 8.21 ms ± 555 µs  | 74.4 ms ± 2.73 ms
```

Comment: I really like this solution. It seems much cleaner and easier to comprehend than that provided by jezrael.

Comment: `Numpy Solution (NP)` is my second solution?

Comment: Sorry, no. It's my solution in this answer.

Comment: So it should be called combinations of pandas/numpy, my second solution is numpy. There is only assign back to column pandas way.

Comment: well, if you don't count .values in the first step. You're right. It's more or less a comparision between 'pd.groupby.cumcount & np.where' and 'pd.rolling & apply(func)'.

Comment: if I find the time i'll add a third option to the benchmark

Comment: Thanks, I use python 3.8, pandas 1.1.1 under win, what is your OS, pandas numpy versions?

Comment: python 3.7.5, pandas 0.25.3, Ubuntu 19.04 on Windows10-WSL

Comment: hmmm, I guess newer versions should not change times so much, for me in edited answer strides is always a bit fastest, I think main reason is working with strings. Numpy like numbers more like strings ;)