# Iterating over each value in column go get 5 previous values in same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Lets say i have dataframe:

| index | x |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 3 | 50 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 11 |
| 6 | 18 |
| 7 | 28 |
| 8 | 22 |
| 9 | 55 |
| 10 | 40 |

And I want to get previous 5 values for every value/index in column x so expected output would be:

| index | x | expected_output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | [null null null null null ] |
| 1 | 20 | null null null null 5 |
| 2 | 25 | null null null 5 20 |
| 3 | 50 | null null 5 20 25 |
| 4 | 10 | null 5 20 25 50 |
| 5 | 11 | 5 20 25 50 10 |
| 6 | 18 | 20 25 50 10 11 |
| 7 | 28 | 25 50 10 11 18 |
| 8 | 22 | 50 10 11 18 28 |
| 9 | 55 | 10 11 18 28 22 |
| 10 | 40 | 11 18 28 22 55 |

I have used this iloc

```
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    print(index,row['x'],df.iloc[-6:-1,2].values)
```

Is there any similar iloc that can solve this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883784/pandas-rolling-values/48884154#48884154) with append missing values:

```
n = 5
x = np.concatenate([[np.nan] * (n), df['x']])

def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

df['expected_output'] = rolling_window(x, n)[:-1].tolist()
print (df)
        x                 expected_output
index                                    
0       5       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
1      20       [nan, nan, nan, nan, 5.0]
2      25      [nan, nan, nan, 5.0, 20.0]
3      50     [nan, nan, 5.0, 20.0, 25.0]
4      10    [nan, 5.0, 20.0, 25.0, 50.0]
5      11   [5.0, 20.0, 25.0, 50.0, 10.0]
6      18  [20.0, 25.0, 50.0, 10.0, 11.0]
7      28  [25.0, 50.0, 10.0, 11.0, 18.0]
8      22  [50.0, 10.0, 11.0, 18.0, 28.0]
9      55  [10.0, 11.0, 18.0, 28.0, 22.0]
10     40  [11.0, 18.0, 28.0, 22.0, 55.0]
```